# Language settings on the Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360

How does the language settings in the Xbox 360 work.

I have set the "Console Settings" > "Language/Locale"  to "English/Sweden" and all the words in the settings menu are in English. But as soon as I go to the Dashboard everything is in Swedish.

Is there a separate language settings for the Dashboard, or is it a bug in the system?

I am using the new fancy dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your Xbox Live account's language? Here are the steps (from [Xbox Support)](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/kinect/dashboard-or-hub-in-another-language):

1. Go to [Billing Account Information](https://live.xbox.com/en-US/account/billingaccountinformation)
2. Sign in using your Microsoft account (this is the e-mail/password tied to your Gamertag)
3. If multiple languages are supported for your country or region, select a language from Preferred Language. Note The Preferred Language option does not appear if only one language is supported (for example, the United States).
4. Click Save.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Didn't work. There was no Preferred Language option in the Billing Account Information page.

Comment: @JonasSöderström Well, was worth a try. Not sure what else to suggest off hand. :(